# how to open this app via my website

Tags: android, android-intent, android-webview

```
 <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="olacabs.com" android:pathPrefix="/app/launch" />
                <data android:scheme="olacabs" android:host="app" android:pathPrefix="/launch" />
            </intent-filter>
```

this is the manifest file of an android app ! how to open this app via my website?

for example i opened linkedin app using this code

```
<a href="linkedin://you"> Linkedin</a>
```

same way  i need to open above app also ! how to do that . i have tried with

```
<a href="olacabs://app/launch">OLA</a>
<a href="olacabs://launch">OLA</a>
<a href="olacabs://app">OLA</a>
```

please help me , thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you put your `intent-filter` in AndroidManifest? Does the actitivy that have this get launched? According to your filter, `http://olacabs.com/app/launch` or `olacabs://app/launch` should fire your activity that has this filter. Try remove one of the `data`.

Comment: http://olacabs.com/app/launch or olacabs://app/launch these are not working, it takes me to webpages and shows me wrong url , i cannot remove it because it is not my app

Comment: You may want to try to remove default application handler set in your device. Maybe you accidentally set some application (like browser) as default handler for the scheme before.

Comment: cannot i open this app via <a> tag?

Comment: <a> tag is not a problem. As long as you declare your activity can handle a URL, and no default application is set to handle that URL (given there are multiple applications declare they want to handle), then a dialog will pop up for you to choose.

Comment: oh , how to set default application to handle URL?

Comment: The pop up will give you an option to choose that application to handle `just once` or `always`. The latter one will make chosen application default handler from that point, unless you clear your preferences.

Comment: no it takes me to browsers not for that application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have figured out by now, but the correct way to have the same activity handle 2 or more URIs is to have multiple `intent-filter`s:

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="olacabs.com" android:pathPrefix="/app/launch" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="olacabs" android:host="app" android:pathPrefix="/launch" />
</intent-filter>
```